# Unable to get the parse value out of multi-line logs in logstash

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to output JSON message to an API. On Simple Log lines, my grok pattern and configurations are working absolutely fine, But I am unable to get the values dynamically out during exceptions and stacktraces.

**Log File :**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:52:59,862]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : TestServiceHttp {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,893]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint********* Sending Message to the Queue*****WSAction: urn:mediate********* Sending Message to the Queue*****SOAPAction: urn:mediate********* Sending Message to the Queue*****MessageID: urn:uuid:d1bbe24a-2ce3-497f-8224-d260b0632506********* Sending Message to the Queue*****Direction: request********* Sending Message to the Queue*****Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><name> Omer</name></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,925]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,933] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/Customer.01.Request.Queue.01?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue URL. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,949] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/Customer.01.Request.Queue.01?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:461)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:372)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleNonBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:204)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:05,009]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:d1bbe24a-2ce3-497f-8224-d260b0632506, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><name> Omer</name></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:00:04,890]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://Omer-PC:8280/services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:630)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:294)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,447]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutdown hook triggered.... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,464]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,477]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Starting to switch to maintenance mode... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,481]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener} -  JMS Listener Shutdown {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener}
```

As you can see in the above logs, that  some are successful log entries and some are exceptions. Following is my logstash configuration file:

**Configuration File:**

```
input {
 stdin {}

    file {
        path => "C:\WSO2Environment\wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\logs\wso2carbon.log" 
        type => "wso2"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
        pattern => "TID:%{SPACE}|(^\s*at .+)|(^.+)"
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
    }

    }
}

filter {

    if [type] == "wso2" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}" ]
            add_tag => [ "grokked" ]        
        }
        mutate {
          gsub => [
             "TimeStamp", "\s", "T",
             "TimeStamp", ",", "."
           ]
        }


    }
    if !( "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] ) {
        grok{
              match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:StackTrace}" ]
              add_tag => [ "grokked" ]  
        }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                target => "TimeStamp"
                timezone => "UTC"
            }
    }

    if ( "multiline" in [tags] ) {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:StackTrace}" ]
            add_tag => [ "multiline" ]
            tag_on_failure => [ "multiline" ]       
        }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                target => "TimeStamp"

            }
    }

}

output {
    stdout { }
     http {
        url => "http://localhost:8086/messages"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "json"
        mapping => ["TimeStamp","%{TimeStamp}","MessageType","%{MessageType}","MessageTitle","%{MessageTitle}","Message","%{log_EventMessage}","SourceSystemId","%{SourceSystemId}","StackTrace","%{log_StackTrace}"]

    }
}
```

**Note:**
In case of single line log entries , this configuration is working fine, but In case of above mentioned exception and stack traces in the above log file, it is not working correctly.

**Current Output in case of exception:**

```
{
  "TimeStamp": "%{TimeStamp}",
  "MessageType": "%{MessageType}",
  "MessageTitle": "%{MessageTitle}",
  "Message": "%{Message}",
  "SourceSystemId": "%{SourceSystemId}",
  "StackTrace": "%{StackTrace}"

}
```

**Expected Output in case of exception:**

```
{
  "TimeStamp": "2001-12-31T12:00:00",
  "StackTrace": " java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)"

}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to achieve three things.

1. First I want that In case of exception all the log entries are sent
   into stack trace element.
2. Second, I want that In case of exception,
   there is no TimeStamp generated in the log file, so I want to map
   the default "@timestamp" attribute to my TimeStamp field.
3. Third , is it possible that In case of exception, only the "TimeStamp" and
   "StackTrace" field is sent towards my api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about your multiline filter? It matches all the lines in your example and since you've got `negate => true`, no lines will be merged together.

Also you don't have any output format to do what you intend to do. You should add something like :

```
if ( "multiline" in [tags] ) { 
  http {
    url => "http://localhost:8086/messages"
    http_method => "post"
    format => "json"
    mapping => ["TimeStamp","%{TimeStamp}","StackTrace","%{StackTrace}"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your way, but it is not allowing me to add two http tags in one configuration file, I can only add this in the output tag of the configuration.

Comment: The code sample in my answer has to be put in the output part of the configuration. It should work that way.